# continuous acceleration in space

Tags: propulsion, relativistic-rocket

If you had a rocket with unlimited fuel and it was continuously firing, would the rocket keep accelerating to a faster and faster speed, or is there a speed limit where acceleration stops

Comment: Theoretically you'll keep accelerating to a greater percentage of the speed of light, but never reach it (it's a mathematical asymptote for anything with mass)

Comment: Unfortunately a rocket with unlimited fuel could never lift up from launch pad on Earth, unlimited thrust and unlimited tank volume would be necessary. If assembeled in orbit, an unlimited number of transfer flights from ground would be necessary to deliver unlimited fuel.

Comment: Duplicate of physics SE question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100730/break-speed-of-light-with-infinite-mass

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html

Answer (score 4):

> would the rocket keep accelerating to a faster and faster speed,
>   or is there a speed limit where acceleration stops

The rocket would keep accelerating and would get ever closer to the speed of light in vacuum. It will not reach that in finite time though. It would never actually **stop** accelerating, though speed gain would slow down.